# Coloring grayscale image as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

I need to dynamically color a grayscale gradient bitmap with ActionScript 3.0. Gradient goes form white to black, the darkest color has to be 0xFF0000, lightest 0xFFFFFF. Tried paletteMap and ColorMatrixFilter with mixed result and no stable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible to do with a ColorMatrixFilter, by building the matrix with a 255 offset on the red channel (but an identity matrix otherwise).

This sample Document class assumes the FLA library has a 720 x 480 exported symbol "GradientBMD" which is a flash.display.BitmapData subclass:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.filters.*;

    public class GreyscaleDemo extends Sprite
    {
        public function GreyscaleDemo()
        {
            var bmd:BitmapData = new GradientBMD(720,480);

            var matrix:Array = new Array();
            matrix = matrix.concat([1,0,0,0,255]);
            matrix = matrix.concat([0,1,0,0,0]);
            matrix = matrix.concat([0,0,1,0,0]);
            matrix = matrix.concat([0,0,0,1,0]);

            var colorFilter:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix);
            bmd.applyFilter(bmd, bmd.rect, new Point(0,0), colorFilter);

            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
            this.addChild(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also create a new bitmapData filled with the color you want the gradient to ramp to (in place of black) and copy it into your gradient with BlendMode.ADD:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.BlendMode;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class GreyscaleDemo extends Sprite
    {
        public function GreyscaleDemo()
        {
            var bmd:BitmapData = new GradientBMD(720,480);
            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
            this.addChild(bitmap);

            var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(720, 480, false, 0xFF0000);
            bmd.draw(bmd2, null, null, BlendMode.ADD, bmd.rect,false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the ColorMatrixFilter example, I special cased it for red. Obviously you can tint your gradient to any arbitrary RGBA color by setting the offsets of each channel. I moved the filter solution to the top of my response because it is the best way to do it if you're tinting to a solid color. You would use the second solution if the tint were non uniform in some way (i.e. you had a second tint bitmap to apply).

Comment: thanks! Since I deal with a lot of transparencies ColorMatrix filter works best. Posted my final solution below - works well with colored as well as grayscale images.

Answer (score 2):

```
        var color:uint = 0xFF0000;
        var r:uint = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        var g:uint = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        var b:uint = color & 0xFF;

        var n:Number = 1/3;

        var matrix:Array = new Array();
        matrix = matrix.concat([n,n,n,0,r]);
        matrix = matrix.concat([n,n,n,0,g]);
        matrix = matrix.concat([n,n,n,0,b]);
        matrix = matrix.concat([0,0,0,1,0]);

        _bitmapData.applyFilter(_bitmapData, _bitmapData.rect, new Point(),  new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix));'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the ColorMatrixFilter (described in another answer) you can also use the **blendMode="luminosity"** option as well.

I have a blog post on grayscale images in ActionScript that might help:
http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2011/01/grayscale-images-progressbar-rating.html